# Better way to use material-system with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to use the stack above to customize Material components with the props provided by the Material system (joining with styled-components).
The component that I'm testing:

```
import React from 'react'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

import { spacing, sizing, color, flexbox, display } from '@material-ui/system'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Row = styled(props => <Grid container {...props} />)`
  ${spacing}
`

export default Row
```

Everything on screen works very well, but an error on console appear every time that I use a material-system prop. Ex.:

> `<Row maxWidth='200px'>...</Row>`

the following error appear on console:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `maxWidth` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `maxwidth` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

I know that the `...props` is passing `maxWidth` to Grid component (and it's a html element), but I'm confusing about how to use it without these console log's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's separate exactly which props are used for styling and which props are sent to the `Grid` component. Using [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Rest_syntax_parameters), we can "pull out" certain properties from the `props` object and send the `rest` to the `Grid` component. Then, the properties that we pull out will form the CSS.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

import { spacing, sizing, color, flexbox, display } from '@material-ui/system'
import styled from 'styled-components'


const Row = styled(
  ({ maxWidth, somethingElse, ...rest }) => <Grid container {...rest} />
)`
  ${spacing}
  maxWidth: ${props => props.maxWidth || defaultValue1};
  somethingElse: ${props => props.somethingElse || defaultValue2};
`;

export default Row
```

Comment: Yes, it works very well, to complement this solution, I've made a helper to separate this props (I'll post as a repose to format like a code)

Answer (score 0):

The `Material-UI` [documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#why-use-material-uis-styling-solution) shows examples of various approaches to styling, including an example showing how to use `styled-components` with `Material-UI`.

Here is the example they show:

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const MyButton = styled(Button)({
  background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
});

export default function StyledComponents() {
  return <MyButton>Styled Components</MyButton>;
}
```

Another approach is using the `Material-UI` hook that uses a CSS-in-JS approach and the `makeStyles` function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

There's also a way to create a [custom theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#createmuitheme-options-args-theme) in a separate file and import it where it's needed. [Here is an example](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme) of the default `Theme` object and what it contains. It's good to take a look at and get an idea of what can be customized by using `createMuiTheme`.

`Material-UI` has multiple approaches to styling and it can be a lot to take in at first. Hope this helps.

Comment: The question asks about passing props.

Answer (score 0):

tanks a lot about the anwsors. Based in these answers, I develop a helper to separate this kind of props:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { spacing, sizing } from "@material-ui/system";

const allowedProps = ({props, system}) => {
    const notAllowedProps = filterProps({props, system})
    const allowedProps = Object.entries(props).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        if (!notAllowedProps.includes(key)) {
            return {...acc, [key]: value}
        }
        return acc
    }, {})
    return allowedProps
}

const filterProps = ({props, system}) => {
    const objSystem = system.reduce((acc, element) => ({
        ...acc,
        ...element(props)
    }), {})
    return Object.keys(objSystem)
}

const ButtonBase = (props) => <Button {...allowedProps({props, system: [spacing, sizing]})} />

const MyButton = styled(ButtonBase)...
```